# CSRF Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, csrf

I want to implement CSRF into my Firebase Functions and because I am using Cookies to send and receive data from to my cloud functions.

As I can understand from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48505572/csrf-protection-with-firebase-email-password-authentication) also I can see that __session cookie is only accepted cookie from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929653/firebase-cloud-function-wont-store-cookie-named-other-than-session/44935288#44935288). So that, csurf package with implementation of cloud function like;

```
const csrf = require("csurf");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const csrfMiddleware = csrf({ cookie: true });
app.use(csrfMiddleware);

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
  res.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", req.csrfToken());
  next();
});
```

wont work. But I could not find any other option right now.

So my implementation on cloud function side, **login.js**

```
 firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(response => {
                let user = response.user;
                let payload = {}
                try {
                    let accessToken = user.xa;
                    let refreshToken = user.refreshToken;
                    res.cookie('__session', accessToken, {
                                httpOnly: true,
                                expires: new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 3600 * 1000),
                                maxAge: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                                secure: true,
                                sameSite: "None"
                            })
                    res.cookie('refresh_token', refreshToken, {
                                httpOnly: true,
                                expires: new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 3600 * 1000),
                                maxAge: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                                secure: true,
                                sameSite: "None"
                            })
                   // other payloads


             res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(payload))
            }).catch(err => {
                return res.status(401).send(err.message)
            })
```

and validation side **validator.js**

```
if(req.cookies) {
        const idToken = req.cookies.__session;
        const verifiedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
        next();
}
```

so question is;

how to implement *csrf* middleware in *firebase cloud functions*? (P.S I am using *firebase hosting* to serve my frontend application).

Comment: Have you seen the Firebase doc [manage session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies)?

Comment: Hello, yes I have read the this documentation but I am not quite sure how to implement it.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?